# Using jQuery to change css in option tags does not work until second click in Angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a edit button that opens a bootstrap modal to edit a record:

```
    <a href="#" ng-click="getAction(action.id, 'edit')"
       data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditAction"
       class="functionalLinks">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
          EDIT
    </a>
```

getAction(action.id, 'edit') looks like this:

```
         $scope.getAction = function (actionId, populateObject) {
            $http.get(actionUrl + '/' + actionId)
               .then(function (response) {
                   // Test front end exception message;
                   // throw "test exception";
                   switch (populateObject) {
                       case "details":
                           $scope.data.actionDetails = response.data;
                           break;
                       case "edit":
                           $scope.data.editAction = response.data;
                           $scope.dimAt1EditActionRecommendedByLerSelections();
                           break;
                   }
               })
               .catch(function (error) {
                   $scope.data.actionDetailsError = error;
               });
        }
```

So we are interested in the "edit" case of the switch:
The response data looks like this (Look at the actionsRecommendedByLer property):

```
{
  "caseId": 8,
  "case": null,
  "actionTypeId": 1,
  "actionType": {
    "actionTypeName": "Actions Taken By Management",
    "caseType": 1,
    "id": 1
  },
  "dateCreated": "2017-05-08T14:55:23.797",
  "actionStatus": 3,
  "notes": "bngfhfrg455",
  "actionType1Id": null,
  "actionType1": {
    "actionId": 1,
    "actionsRecommendedByLer": [
      {
        "actionType1Id": 1,
        "lookUpDetailId": 4,
        "name": "Alternative Discipline Agreement in lieu of # day Suspension",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "actionType1Id": 1,
        "lookUpDetailId": 7,
        "name": "Arbitration",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "actionType1Id": 1,
        "lookUpDetailId": 13,
        "name": "Complaint - EEO Formal",
        "id": 3
      }
    ],
    "actionProposedBySupervisorId": 4,
    "actionProposedBySupervisor": {
      "id": 4,
      "displayValue": "Alternative Discipline Agreement in lieu of # day Suspension",
      "code": "",
      "parentId": null,
      "externalSystemId": null,
      "isInactive": false,
      "inactivDate": null,
      "sortOrder": null,
      "discriminator": "",
      "lookupMaster": null,
      "lookUpMastersId": 1
    },
    "actionTakenBySupervisorId": 8,
    "actionTakenBySupervisor": {
      "id": 8,
      "displayValue": "AWOL Letter (CORPS)",
      "code": "",
      "parentId": null,
      "externalSystemId": null,
      "isInactive": false,
      "inactivDate": null,
      "sortOrder": null,
      "discriminator": "",
      "lookupMaster": null,
      "lookUpMastersId": 1
    },
    "actionCharges": [
      {
        "actionType1Id": 1,
        "lookUpDetailId": 211,
        "name": "Creating hostile work environment",
        "id": 1
      }
    ],
    "actionEffectiveDate": "2017-05-16T04:00:00",
    "id": 1
  },
  "actionType17Id": null,
  "actionType17": null,
  "id": 1
}
```

And I use the response data to show a table with detete buttons basically showing which Select Options are chosen like this:

```
    <select class="pull-right" id="editActionRecommendedByLerSelect"
            ng-model="data.editAction.actionType1.actionRecommendedByLerId">
        @*<option value="0"></option>*@
        <option value="{{managmentAction.id}}"
                ng-repeat="managmentAction in data.managementActions">
            {{managmentAction.displayValue}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <br />
    @*{{data.editAction.actionType1.actionRecommendedByLerId}}*@
    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
        <tr ng-show="data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer.length == 0">
            <td colspan="2" class="noResultText">No Actions Recommended By LER</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="actionRecommendedByLer in data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer">
            <td>
                <a href="#" ng-click="removeAnEditActionRecommendedByLerFromActionType1(actionRecommendedByLer.id)"
                   class="functionalLinks text-danger">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    DELETE
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>@*{{actionRecommendedByLer.id}} :*@ {{actionRecommendedByLer.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The select is populated by an array of choices.  The choice ID will match the appropritate lookupDetailId of the actionRecommendedByLer id. in the collection.

This line in the "edit" case of the switch in $scope.getAction(actionId, populateObject):

```
$scope.dimAt1EditActionRecommendedByLerSelections();
```

calls this:

```
$scope.dimAt1EditActionRecommendedByLerSelections = function () {
            console.log("In dimAt1EditActionRecommendedByLerSelections");
            console.log("Length: " + $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer.length);
            var element;       
            for (i = 0; i < $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer.length; i++) {
                console.log("i: " + i);
                console.log("id: " + $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer[i].lookUpDetailId);
                element = $('#editActionRecommendedByLerSelect option[value = "' + $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer[i].lookUpDetailId + '"]');
                element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
            }
        }
```

Basically I am using jQuery to make the  multiple options already selected in the select drop down yellow and disabled.  This was easy from my Add Bootstrap modal.
But loading it all back in for an edit and hightlighting the right ones is proving to be way more difficult.

This works and shows in the Select Drop Down the choice names highlighted in yellow and disabled in the model being rendered in a table next to a delete button. The only problem is it doesn't show the choices hightlighted until I click the edit button again.

[image]

How can I get this to hightlight and disable the options on the first edit click?

---

**UPDATE 1** (In response to comment user1120808)

I tried your answer but it is not working. In fact now it does not even work on the second click.

Does this look like correct implementation of your suggestion?

```
$scope.dimAt1EditActionRecommendedByLerSelections = function () {
            console.log("In dimAt1EditActionRecommendedByLerSelections");
            console.log("Length: " + $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer.length);
            var element;       
            for (i = 0; i < $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer.length; i++) {
                console.log("i: " + i);
                console.log("id: " + $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer[i].lookUpDetailId);
                // force scope digest.
                $scope.$evalAsync(() => {
                    element = $('#editActionRecommendedByLerSelect option[value = "' + $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer[i].lookUpDetailId + '"]');
                    element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see it, is because jquery runs outside of angular and angular doesn't pick it up. It isn't evaluated anymore. But with the second click you trigger a digest cycle, so you see it then. So what you need to do is force a digest cycle. You can use [$evalAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) for this.

try the following:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(() => {
    element = $('#editActionRecommendedByLerSelect option[value = "' + $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer[i].lookUpDetailId + '"]');
    element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$timeout service solved the problem:

```
    $scope.dimAt1EditActionRecommendedByLerSelections = function () {
            console.log("In dimAt1EditActionRecommendedByLerSelections");
            console.log("Length: " + $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer.length);
            $timeout(function() {
                var element;
                for (i = 0; i < $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer.length; i++) {
                    console.log("i: " + i);
                    console.log("id: " + $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer[i].lookUpDetailId);
                    element = $('#editActionRecommendedByLerSelect option[value = "' + $scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer[i].lookUpDetailId + '"]');
                    element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
```